# Extracting text from PPT and pasting it in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I need to extract data from text boxes in a PowerPoint presentation and put them in respective cells in an Excel worksheet.

I have searched but can't find a suitable work-around.

This code is to print the text from slides. I can't understand how to arrange it in Excel cells.

```vb
Dim oPApp As Object
Dim oSlide As Object
Dim oShape As Object
    
Set oPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    
For Each oSlide In oPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
        
        If oShape.Type = 1 Or oShape.Type = 14 Then
            Debug.Print oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        End If
            
    Next oShape
Next oSlide
    
Set oPApp = Nothing
```

**Example of slide (Input):**
[image: Example of PPT slide (Input)]

**Example of sheet (Output):**
[image: Example of excel sheet (Output)]

Comment: If the code sample in your post is working for you, then the next thing for you to explore is _Office Automation_ in the form of creating an Excel `Application` object and opening a workbook, then setting up a worksheet and adding your data to the cells. Take a look at [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/open-excel-file-using-vba-from-powerpoint-and-auto/7beb812e-4c38-4c38-aa2e-629a164b3ab3?db=5) and [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/378627-powerpoint-vba-open-excel-click.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you want it to be done from Excel module (it could be done from PowerPoint Module also), I just adding some codes & suggestions to your code. However it is to be mentioned while looping through Shapes in a PowerPoint Slide It generally comes in order of creation of the shape. So for maintaining proper sequence of the fields, you have to work out some way sort them according to their position (i.e. top, left property or any other criteria according to the presentation). Try

```
    Dim oPApp As Object
    Dim oSlide As Object
    Dim oShape As Object

    Dim Rw, StCol, Col, Sht As Long
    Rw = 2     'Starting Row of Target excel data
    StCol = 1   'Starting Column of Target excel data
    Sht = 3   'Target Worksheet no.

    Set oPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    'It will only work for already opened active presentation
    'It can also be suugested that first create a powerpoint object and then open desired preesntation fron the path

    For Each oSlide In oPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides
    Col = StCol
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            If oShape.Type = 1 Or oShape.Type = 14 Then
            '    Debug.Print oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            'Next line was added for putting the data into excel sheet
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht).Cells(Rw, Col).Value = 
 oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            End If
        Col = Col + 1
        Next oShape
    Rw = Rw + 1
    Next oSlide

    Set oPApp = Nothing
```

however one word of caution msoTextBox type is 17 and type 14 is msoPlaceholder.

Comment: You'd also want to test PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType for Type 14 shapes.  That'll tell you whether the placeholder contains text or something else.  If something else, there might not be a TextFrame to extract text from, and trying to extract text would throw an error.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg doesn't he already do that? `If oShape.Type = 1 Or oShape.Type = 14 Then`

Comment: Thanks a ton all of you guys! @Ahmed the code works really well (thanks again!). There's a piece of advise I want from all of you experts - Currently the code extracts everything in msoTextBox type 17 and places it in excel column B or C (apparently Field A, B, C, D are contained in one text box), however I want Field A to be extracted in one column, B in another, so and so forth. Do you think I should use "Find" in VBA, then extract characters between Field A and B and then export it to excel, or that would just over-complicate the code and I should just use excel formulae to achieve that?

Comment: @Marucciboy2 No. A Type 14 (ie placeholder) object can hold text, charts, pictures, video, smartart, etc. Try inserting a new title+content slide, click the content placeholder's Chart icon, then do Debug.Print ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Textframe,Textrange.Text.  You'll get an error message.

Comment: @user10434129 What does the text in the text box look like? If the fields are delimited by some unique character, VBA's SPLIT command will do the lifting for you.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg The fields are not limited by any unique character :(
Field A, B, C are strings, but they are separated by the respective headers, for example : 
Field A Title : abcbadf
Field B Title : djdjvhfkd
Field C Title : cdjhjdkd
One of the work-arounds I could think of is find end of the string 'Field A Title :' and start of the string 'Field B Title :' and extract everything in between, so that I get 'abcbadf'. This can be achieved by excel formulae as well though, but I thought VBA will be more fool-proof. I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @user10434129 I see. Either way should work, especially if you're plugging the data into a known XL file (ie, one that has the formulae pre-entered). If you can't prepare the XL formulae in advance, parsing the data in VBA would, I think, be the best way.