# Trying to build a macro to copy textboxes from Powerpoint to Ex

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Attempted to use early binding to assign a powerpoint presentation to a variable so i can call it again to dig deeper into the slides and then shapes to copy textboxes into Excel

but pptApp.**Presentations**.Open("Presentation1.pptx") keeps getting highlighted for "compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference"

```
Sub test()

Dim pptApp As Application
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

pptApp.Visible = True

pptApp .Presentations.Open("Presentation1.pptx")


End Sub
```

I am familiar with working my way around Excel's object library but powerpoint is still quite new to me and I can't find much information online regarding copying items from powerpoint into excel as usually its done the other way round, would appreciate any additional advice on the useful codes in Powerpoint object library (this is a personal project to automate a mundane task at work)

Comment: The error is because of the space `pptApp .Presentations`. Fix that and you get type mismatch because of `pptApp As Application` which should be `pptApp As Powerpoint.Application`. If you still get error add path to filename `pptApp.Presentations.Open Path & "\Presentation1.pptx"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940624

Comment: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/powerpoint-macro-examples-tutorial/