# Extracting text from powerpoint into Excel in the same format

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm looking to extract text from powerpoint into excel so I can copy it into outlook later on hopefully in the same format as much as possible.

The text is paragraphed and looks something like this on powerpoint.
[Paragraphed Powerpoint text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59VWg.png)

I had help from this article: ([Extracting text from PPT and pasting it in Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570289/extracting-text-from-ppt-and-pasting-it-in-excel-using-vba)) in working the vba code to extract text from powerpoint. However the text extracted into the excel cell is clumped together like that ([excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zokvQ.png)). Does anyone know how I can keep the paragraph formatting (including arrows) while extracting the text into a cell on excel?

The below code was taken from user Ahmed AU which can be found here and I'm using it in this post because I intend to work off it  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573908/15567184

```
Sub LateBinding()

Dim oPApp As Object
Dim oSlide As Object
Dim oShape As Object

Dim Rw, StCol, Col, Sht As Long
Rw = 8
StCol = 1
Sht = 1

Set oPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

For Each oSlide In oPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides
Col = StCol
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
        If oShape.Type = 1 Or oShape.Type = 14 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht).Cells(Rw, Col).Value = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        End If
    Col = Col + 1
    Next oShape
Rw = Rw + 1

Next oSlide
Set oPApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Normally, PowerPoint text is formatted by the bodyStyle XML section in the slide master, which is then inherited by the layouts and then by the slides. The slide text has no formatting information attached unless the master formatting has been over-ridden in the slide. It will be a complex project to try to capture that in Excel, and then transfer that to Outlook, which both have different methods of formatting text.

Comment: Each .TextRange in PPT has a .Runs collection, where each .Run represents a bit of text that's differently formatted from the previous bit and returns just the text with that bit of formatting. From that you can pick up the font/color/size etc and the character range within the overall text box that it applies to. From recording a macro while formatting some text in a cell in Excel, it appears that you'd be able to do the job.